# how can add GIF images in viewPager in android

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, animated-gif, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to create image slider using viewPager into fragment in Bottom Navigation Bar in android. 
I wanna load GIF images into viewPager but it is not working.If it is  possible please let me know how it is possible 
This is my xml code.

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
               android:id="@+id/mainviewPager1"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


 </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my HomeFragment class where i am adding viewPager into fragment.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment 
{
        ViewPager viewPager;

        public HomeFragment()
        {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
           View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.mainviewPager1);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

           ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

            }

            return v;
    }
```

This is my viewPagerAdaper.java code.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Integer[] images={R.drawable.fimage,R.drawable.simage,R.drawable.timage};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.customimageView2);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view,0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ViewPager vp=(ViewPager) container;
        View v=(View) object;
        vp.removeView(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to narrow down the code, only post the relevant part.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` doesn't support GIF format, if you want to deal with GIF images you can use this library https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable and include `pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView` inside your `custom_layout.xml`.

Replace your `ImageView` with a `GifImageView`